# Estimate Variance-Covariance matrix via Error Propagation of Weighted Least Squares Equation

Tags: covariance-matrix, weighted-regression, error-propagation

Given a linear system $b_{obs} = Ax$, how can I derive the covariance of $x$ (i.e. $C$) from the weighted least square solution equation: $$x = (A^TS^{−1}A)^{-1}A^TS^{−1}b_{obs}$$ With $C$ being the variance covariance matrix of $x$:
$$C = (A^TS^{−1}A)^{-1}$$?

We assume that errors in $b_{obs}$ are normally distributed and independent with covariance $S$

We also assume that we weight observations inversely proportional to their variance.

---

[The Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_least_squares#Parameter_errors_and_correlation) yields the following (Changed to keep notation the same):

> An expression for the estimated variance-covariance matrix of the
> parameter estimates can be obtained by error propagation from the
> errors in the observations. Let the variance-covariance matrix for the
> observations be denoted by $M$ and that of the estimated parameters by
> $C$.
>
> $C = (A^TS^{-1}A)^{-1}A^TS^{-1}MS^{-1T}A(A^TS^{-1T}A)^{-1}$

Which of course simplifies to $C = (A^TS^{−1}A)^{-1}$ if $S^{-1} = M^{-1}$

However, I am unclear on how the variance-covariance matrix for the estimated parameters was derived.